# Function to extract the part starting from a substring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Lets say i have the following string:

```
var myString = "hello and welcome to my website";
```

Is there any function in Javascript to extract the part starting from a given substring?

For exemple:

```
var newString = extractString(myString, "welcome");
```

And `newString` will be `"welcome to my website"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```
> myString = "hello and welcome to my website"
"hello and welcome to my website"
> part = myString.substr(myString.indexOf("welcome"))
"welcome to my website"
```

Note that this assumes the substring to be there, if this might not be the case, add a check:

```
var i = myString.indexOf(search)
if(i >= 0)
   ...ok
```